# my regex is not catching required pattern in text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am trying to extract duration using regex,

Example text,

```
text = "Google, Inc 09/19 - 09/20 CA, USA"
```

Here, is the regex I have,

```
pattern = fr"""
(?:
  (
    \d\d(?:\.|\/)\d\d\d\d|
    (?:{months_abr})?
    (?:{months_exp})?
    (?:
      (?:[\s\.\/\-]?\d{{2,4}})
    )
  )\s*(?:\-|to|\s)\s*
  (
    \d\d(?:\.|\/)\d\d\d\d|
    (?:{months_abr})?
    (?:{months_exp})?
    (?:
      (?:[\s\.\/\-]?\d{{2,4}})
    )|
    current|present|till\s?\-?date|till\s?\-?now|till\s?\-?date|to\s\-?present|until\s?\-?now|till\s?\-?now
  )
)"""

find_all = re.findall(
    pattern, text, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE
)
```

The output I am getting,

```
[('/19', '09')]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: This is my desired output, `('09/19', '09/20')`. my current regex takes care of other pattern like `(march 1996, april 2020)` but my regex is failing for the above text I don't know why.

Comment: I have tried to optimize the pattern a bit, and I think [this one](https://regex101.com/r/Qw9wTd/2) can be the regex you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
pattern = fr"""
(?<!\d)                          # A position not immediately preceded with digit
(                                # Group 1
  (?:\d?\d[./])?\d\d(?:\d\d)?    # one or two digits and . or / (optionally), two or four digits
  |                              # or
  (?:{months_abr}|{months_exp}) [\s./-]? \d\d(?:\d\d)? # month, space/dot/slash/hyphen and then two/four digits
)                                # end of Group 1 
\s*(?:-|to)\s*                   # - or "to" enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
(                                # Group 2
    (?:\d?\d[./])?\d\d(?:\d\d)?  
  |
    (?:{months_abr}|{months_exp}) [\s./-]?\d\d(?:\d\d)?
  |
    current|present|(?:un)?till\s?-?(?:date|now|date)|to\s-?present # some alternatives denoting time
)
"""
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eZRQHx). Output: `[('09/19', '09/20')]`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qw9wTd/5).

Note: I decided to use `\d\d` instead of `\d{2}` to keep the code shorter since inside f-strings you need to use `{{` and `}}` to define literal curly braces, and they make the string look ugly here.

Comment: This regex is not working for date like `3/2006-6/2007`, what can I change to match this pattern?

Comment: @user_12 change `\d\d[./]\d\d(?:\d\d)?` to `\d?\d[./]\d\d(?:\d\d)?`. I also suggest adding `(?<!\d)` at the start. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qw9wTd/4).

Comment: In between I have one pattern like `2017 - present` (or) `2015 - 2018`, please help me catch that pattern too? I tried but couldn't figure out what to change.

Comment: @user_12 It is easy, just make the day matching part optional, like `(?:\d?\d[./])?\d\d(?:\d\d)?`, see the [updated regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qw9wTd/5).

Comment: Thank you, Can you please update it in the answer once, I am bit confused by looking there.